# How to add a line to a google spreadsheet via email?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, automation, google-sheets

I need a google apps script which can do the following:
if I send an email to my alias email, say to myemail+expenses@gmail.com, it adds a line in a specific google spreadsheet with data from that email. E.g. timestamp, subject, the first line of a body - whatever.

I found interesting article describing similar process of [sending data to google spreadsheet](https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/).

May be there is no any direct way of doing that, however, it should exist some workaround.

P.S. It should be done only by using a google echosystem. No php, servers etc.

Comment: There is no trigger for a script to run when an email is sent.  So, if that's what you want, it can't be done.  If the email is being sent with Apps Script, then the same script can do what you want.  You can also trigger a stand alone Apps Script from a link.  So, you could trigger code to run from clicking a link to the "exec" URL of the Published Apps Script.

Comment: You can achieve what you want (ie: run a script when an email is sent) using pushingbox's email API to trigger a customURL request to a Google script. The email sent to pushingbox is a trigger. when you  get an email in your gmail alias, also forward it to pushingbox using your developer id (https://www.pushingbox.com/api.php) (setup a service and scenario). You can either do a 'cc' when you send the original email, or setup a filter within gmail which will auto-forward certain emails based on a filter. (http://www.komku.org/2013/10/how-to-use-filters-to-forward-certain-emails.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are two step for this.

#### #1

At first create a trigger to run the mail checker.

```
function switchTrigger() {
    var isExist = false;
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
        if ( /*<CONDITION>*/ ) {
            isExist = true;
            ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
        }
    }
    if (!isExist) {
        ScriptApp.newTrigger( /*<CONDITION>*/ ).create();
        Logger.log('create');
    }
}
```

#### #2

Then you have to check emails. Something like that

```
function checkMail() {
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById(properties.targetSheetId).getSheets()[0];
    var query = /* properties.queryString */ ;
    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
    if (threads.length < 1) return;
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
            if (messages[j].isStarred()) {
                sh.appendRow([
                    new Date(),
                    messages[j].getFrom(),
                    messages[j].getPlainBody()
                ]);
                messages[j].unstar();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Be careful**. You have to set up Gmail filters so that all incoming to `myemail+expenses@gmail.com` would be marked with an star at the beginning.

[Working Example](https://gist.github.com/oshliaer/ea6597e8c7b48ffe695c)

Comment: Beautiful! Alexander, which benefits do we have from not setting a minute's trigger manually?

Comment: And I just have made 2 small amendments:
1. to the end of `messages[j].getPlainBody()` I have added `.trim()` - to get rid of final ugly break string;
2. Changed a bit vice versa - to mark the threads with a star after they they have come to the spreadsheet. But this is just the matter of taste :)

Comment: Don't use `.everyMinutes(1)` everytime. This is an example. Triggers total runtime has a limit https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas?hl=en

Comment: Well, I got the idea with a quota for running triggers. I just didn't grasp the idea with the setting the trigger programmatically. Could you please explain it?